# Raise event or pass delegate for feedback from method - which is better?

Tags: c#, .net

Say you have a helper method which performs a long running and complicated data crunching task, which you run from a background thread, and you need feedback from the method to show the user. Which of these strategies would you say is best and way?

1. Pass a delegate to the method e.g. CrunchData(ShowFeedbackDelegate showFeedback)
2. Raise an event at certain key points during the method which contains the feedback message (e.g. 'Processing 1 of 100).

Comment: Option 2 is what many frameworks do and I think it is a very good option.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a BackgroundWorker:

```
        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            // do something long running
            for (int i = 1; i <= records.Count; i++)
            {
                DisplayMessage("process " + i + " of " + records.Count);
                ProcessRecord(records[i]);
            }
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted+= (s, e) =>
        {
            // report to user
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, the CrunchData method is being called in DoWork but we need feedback from the CrunchData method e.g. "Processing 10 of 1000". How would you do this?

Comment: You can use ProgressChanged event for tracking progress in BackgroundWorker

Comment: Your `DoWork` function can call `ReportProgress` which in turn calls `ProgressChanged`.

Comment: That's fine if the crunching is happening directly in the DoWork method but in my case the crunching is happening in the Helper.CrunchData method which is in a different class library from the main app. So the CrunchData method still needs some way of providing feedback as it doesn't have access to the ReportProgress method or ProgressChanged event. What it needs is to either have a delegate passed in or report its own progress with its own progress changed event, which is better? Or is there some other better way?

Comment: Go with the event and register to it from outside. If backgroundworker uses that approach with ReportProgress method and ProgressChanged event, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel, use TPL.
Wrap long running operation in task, and use [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd270696.aspx) method

```
public Task<MyCustomStatus> LongRunningOperationAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                                 {
                                      //Long Running method here
                                      return myCustomStatus;
                                 });
}
```

and outside

```
LongRunningOperationAsync().ContinueWith(t=>
                                         {
                                              if(t.Exception == null)
                                              {
                                                 //Something bad happen
                                              }
                                              //Task finished
                                         });
```

TPL gives you enough flexibility to solve most async problems

Comment: I know how to run the method async. My question is about the best way to provide feedback to the user from a method which is being run async.

Comment: I would pass some interface to async method, and track method call... in this case, just it is simple, and easy to do with TPL

Answer (score 0):

Raise Events, that is what events are made for, and remember, events are delegates at last...

Comment: That's what I think too :) The reason I'm asking this question is I usually raise events for things like this to keep my layers nicely decoupled - calling code can listen or ignore as it likes. But I've recently seen delegates being passed into methods all over the project I'm working on and I need to sort it out in my head why events are better before I do a code review.